# django unique together and triggers

Tags: django, triggers, django-admin

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    address = models.TextField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=STATE_CHOICES, blank=True)
    pincode = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('first_name', 'last_name',)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        slug = slugify(self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name)
        super(Customer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I have a `before insert or update trigger` on the database which normalizes first_name, last_name, ie 1st letter upper case, rest to lower case.
the save function on the model throws integrity error on unique_together because of the trigger.
suppose we have

```
first_name : 'Abcd'
last_name : 'Defg'
```

in the database.

if i add a new record in the admin with

```
first_name : 'abcd'
second_name: 'defg'
```

then the error is not caught by django admin.
any suggestions on how to deal with this.

Comment: Django checks the uniqueness before executing the INSERT. I think you'll have to add the validation to check for case insensitive values.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this :

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.first_name = self.first_name.title()
    self.last_name = self.last_name.title()
    slug = slugify(self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name)
    super(Customer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```